# Quartz schedule except specific time

Tags: quartz-scheduler, cronexpression

Is it possible to create a CronExpression with: "fire every 5 min but not run at 00:05 and 00:10"?

```
org.quartz.CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule("0 0/5 * * * ?")
```

Answer (score 1):

You will have to use two expressions:

```
0 15/5 0 * * ?
0 0/5 1-23 * * ?
```

The first expression is specific to 12 AM, the second is for the rest of the time.